# NEO GUI "Execution terminated in fault state"

Tags: blockchain

Hi I am a newbie in NEO blockchain, trying to deploy my first contract using neo-gui.
I am following this toturial:
https://freestartupkits.com/articles/technology/cryptocurrency-news-and-tips/ultimate-neo-smart-contract-tutorial/#part4

on "Invoke your second smart contract" I get error "execution terminated in fault state" (see image below).

I believe that I have enough gas. How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a compatibility issue in the contract compiler.

You will have to return to the point where you had built and deployed the neo-compiler. Open the project for neo-compiler, find the `neon/Program.cs:line 26` and amend the line that sets the `bCompatible` as:

```
bool bCompatible = true;
```

Then re-build, re-deploy, the compiler and recompile your contract with the new compiler.

I know, this is not entertaining.

Alternatively one may be able to pass the `--compatible` flag to the compiler when building the contract but that is too much for a VS newbie such as me.